# pretty url search string instead of question marks

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have been looking at other websites and see when you search, primary something like a search term, location and category you will see a pretty url like:

```
example.com/black-boots/new-york/shoes
```

instead of what I have now which is something like:

```
example.com/search-results/search?=black+boots&city=new+york&category=shoes
```

In my route I could start with something like:

```
router.get('/search-results/:search/:city/:category', shopController.getSearchResults);
```

And in the controller I could use `req.params.city` and so on to get the values from the url but the part that I can't figure out is a good way to get the text input values into the url using a get request.

Using GET by default gives me the 'ugly' looking url.

Basically the part that needs to go into the form

```
<form method="GET" action="/search-results/search/city/category">
```

Comment: Do the submit in JavaScript: read the values of the inputs, concatenate into a URL, then either change the window location (GET) or construct your own `HTMLFormElement` and `submit` it (POST). Note: none of this is serverside, so [tag:node.js], [tag:express] and [tag:ejs] are not applicable.

Comment: @amadan, I was thinking about that but was hoping there would be a less long-winded way. Just to make sure I am on the same page as you, do you mean something like this? `document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', e => {
         e.preventDefault();
         const city = document.getElementById('city').value;
        alert(city);
     })`

Comment: Yes, something like this. The URL that a form posts to is fixed and unchangeable by anything in HTML; you need JavaScript if you wish it to be dynamic.

Comment: @Amadan, okay, I will give that a try. Is it terrible or frowned upon to have the search string I currently have with the questions marks etc? I ask because I have that working already and now I would have to kind of start all over.

Comment: There is technically (i.e. to me as an engineer) nothing wrong with it, though subjectively (i.e. to some users) one might be thought of as "prettier" than the other. (There is another solution without JavaScript, but that one _is_ inferior: serverside accept the "ugly" version, prettify it and do a serverside redirect. It is slower, wastes resources, only to prettify a URL - bad all around.)

Comment: I agree with you, that sounds like a waste of time and resources just to make a url pretty. I think either leaving it as is or using javascript in the way you mentioned earlier will be my best bet. Thank you for you advice, I am grateful. If you turn this into an answer I can award you an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments, plus this code sample for a GET request:

```
const form = document.getElementById('searchform');
form.addEventListener('submit', evt => {
  const who = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('who').value);
  const where = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('where').value);
  const what = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('what').value);
  window.location.href = `/${who}/${where}/${what}`;
}
```

Comment: last thing I just noticed using your way. If there is a space in the word the url looks like new%20york. Do I need to use some code to convert spaces to dashes here or what would your suggestion be? Suppose I could use str_replace or split or some method here...

Comment: The percent signs are normal part of URI encoding. I added code to do it explicitly. If your backend expects `new-york` instead of `New York`, then by all means do transform them; but if not, then that would just mess you up (given that mostly such transforms are irreversible).

Comment: Ah, I see your point. My database has New York so if I now send it new-york it won't find it.